# Visual studio deploy AWS Lambda for non prod environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-lambda

I have deployed and able to use a webApi published to AWS Lambda, but it is always "prod"

I want to now setup test/dev environments

If i right click the project and choose to "Publish to AWS Lambda", there is no option to change the env.

I have however, found in my project a "serverless.template" file, which contains the following:

```
"Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    },
```

So, my question is, do i just need to change the Fn::Sub to be "/Dev/" instead of "/Prod/" and if not, how will i publish to a dev environment?

Thank you

UPDATE:
I have created a stages "stage" called Dev now:
[image]

so i guess the next stop is to deploy from visual studio, however, there is no way to select this stage when trying to deploy?

Comment: Have you created a `Dev` stage for your API in your project?

Comment: @Marcin no, i was hoping i just need to change that value, so it will get published to a new location with "dev" in the url

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work like that. Depending on how you have setup your project, generally you would need  to have separate `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` for `Dev`. I'm not sure how to setup it up in serverless, thus can't provide more detailed answer.

Comment: @Marcin thank you, i just found i can create stages in AWS for API Gateway, so i have now created a dev stage, and it lets you pick a "deploy" to use... however, i need to publish to this still, when i make a change in visual studio

Comment: No problem. I'm not a visual studio user, thus don't know how to set it up there. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `Prod` to `Dev` it will output the URL for a API Gateway stage named `Dev`.

If you're using API Gateway then having a separate [stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html) for each environment is a good approach to seperate.

Regarding deploying Lambdas you should use an [Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html) for each environments version to ensure you don't accidently update prod.

Then within API Gateway create a [stage variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html) and reference this for the Arn to the Lambda alias so that the Dev stage will use the Dev Alias.

If you have seperate accounts between prod and non prod then these won't collide, although I always believe its better to us clear naming conventions for environments to avoid confusion.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the answer, i created a stage called dev in API Gateway, but i want to deploy to that from Visual Studio each time i make a code change?

Comment: The Lambda is not deployed to API Gateway, in fact your API Gateway references a Lambda ARN. If you can use a Lambda alias you can ensure your code goes only to dev :)

Comment: thanks again, it just seems a bit over complicated, the elastic beanstalk for running MVC or razor pages, you just deploy and pick what environment you want to upload to, no idea why they didnt apply this same simple logic to webApi projects... Maybe there is some reason :(

Comment: Yeah I can understand theres a few more steps, although I guess you are more in control of any components here. With Elastic Beanstalk the service covers everything from scaling, to deployment, to version separations. With API Gateway it calls other endpoints (Lambda in your case) so you need to carry out the extra steps to ensure you don't accidently deploy to production. A lot of organisations end up also using multiple accounts to reduce the risk of this :)

Comment: ok, thanks for your help :) im going to try to understand the links you provided in your answer and see if i can do it that way, otherwise, i may just go for the multiple account option lol, thanks again :)

Comment: No problem, feel free to raise any further issues you have and I'll try to assist :)